# Assigning a subsection of C-style array using a std::array& without violating "strict aliasing" and hence invoking UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing, stdarray

Can I use a `std::array<int, N>` to alias parts of a `int[]` without invoking UB?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array
"This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member."

Motivation: The `copy` function below is not under my control and needs to make a single assignment via references. Only a `struct { int[N]; }` like a `std::array<int, N>` can make that kind of "multiple object assignment"?

Is this UB?

Is there another way?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <std::size_t N>
void print(int (&arr)[N], std::size_t number_rows, std::size_t number_cols) {
    assert(number_rows * number_cols == N);
    for (std::size_t r = 0; r != number_rows; ++r) {
        for (std::size_t c = 0; c != number_cols; ++c) {
            std::cout << arr[r * number_cols + c] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void copy(std::array<int, 4>& a, std::array<int, 4>& b) {
  b = a;
}


int main() {

    int vals[16] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};

    print(vals, 4, 4);

    auto s1 = reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 4>*>(&vals[0]);
    auto s2 = reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 4>*>(&vals[4]);

    copy(*s2, *s1);

    print(vals, 4, 4);

}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 

5 6 7 8 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16
```

## Edit: The Wider problem

Thanks for all the comments / answers. By popular request I am posting the wider problem for more context.

I am going to do that in 2 levels.

### Level 1

This is the next layer out of what I would like to do:

```cpp
#include "range/v3/algorithm/remove.hpp"
#include "range/v3/view/chunk.hpp"
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8, 
        9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16
    };

    auto chunked = ranges::views::chunk(v, 4);
    auto it = ranges::remove(chunked, 9, [](const auto& e) { return e[0]; }); // <== compile error

    // expected result  (xx = unspecified)
    // std::vector<int> v{
    //     1, 2, 3, 4,
    //     5, 6, 7, 8, 
    //     13, 14, 15, 16,
    //     xx, xx, xx, xx
    // };
    // and it pointing at chunked[3] (ie the row of xx)  
}
```

But `ranges::remove` complains that the `ranges::view::chunk` is "not permutable". This was confirmed here:
https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/1760

So my next attempt was writing a "chunked range" which I could pass to ranges::remove. I did this in multiple ways. Several "worked" but are based on UB, including this way of using std::array<int,4> as a "chunk proxy" (and hence the OP above):

```cpp
#include "range/v3/algorithm/remove.hpp"
#include "range/v3/view/chunk.hpp"
#include "range/v3/view/zip.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class Integers {

  public:
    struct Iterator {
        using chunk             = std::array<int, 4>;
      
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type        = chunk;
        using pointer           = value_type*;
        using reference         = value_type&;
template <class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate, class ChunkedForwardIt>
ForwardIt remove_if_par(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p,
    ChunkedForwardIt chunked_first, std::ptrdiff_t chunk_size) {
    auto first_orig = first;
    first           = std::find_if(first, last, p);
    // advance chunked_first in lockstep. TODO this is linear compelxity unless random_access_iter
    std::advance(chunked_first, std::distance(first_orig, first) * chunk_size);
    if (first != last) {
        ForwardIt        i       = first;
        ChunkedForwardIt chunk_i = chunked_first;
        while (++i != last) {
            std::advance(chunk_i, chunk_size);
            if (!p(*i)) {
                *first++ = std::move(*i);
                // move chunk
                auto loop_chunk_i = chunk_i;
                for (std::ptrdiff_t ci = 0; ci != chunk_size; ++ci)
                    *chunked_first++ = std::move(*loop_chunk_i++);
            }
        }
    }
    return first;
}

        Iterator();
        Iterator(int* ptr) : current_row_(reinterpret_cast<chunk*>(ptr)) {}  // <== UB here

        reference operator*() const { return *current_row_; }
        pointer   operator->() { return current_row_; }
        Iterator& operator++() {
            ++current_row_;
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator operator++(int) {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        friend bool operator==(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) {
            return a.current_row_ == b.current_row_;
        }
        friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) {
            return a.current_row_ != b.current_row_;
        }

      private:
        chunk* current_row_;
    };

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&data_[0]); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(&data_[16]); }

    int data_[16];
};

template <std::size_t N>
void print(int (&arr)[N], std::size_t number_rows, std::size_t number_cols) {
    assert(number_rows * number_cols == N);
    for (std::size_t r = 0; r != number_rows; ++r) {
        for (std::size_t c = 0; c != number_cols; ++c) {
            std::cout << arr[r * number_cols + c] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    Integers chunked{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
    print(chunked.data_, 4, 4);

    auto it = ranges::remove(chunked, 9, [](const auto& e) { return e[0]; });

    print(chunked.data_, 4, 4);
```

Output (as desired but based on UB)

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 

1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
13 14 15 16 
13 14 15 16
```

### Level 2

The reason for being quite keen on using ranges, is because there is another layer outwards for my desired algorithm, in that there is actually a 1D parallel vector which I zipped together with the chunked one and then the remove condition is based on the 1D vector.

Note that both vectors are reasonably large here (~100-500k items), so I want to *avoid making a copy*. This is why I am not using `|` composition and the lazy `ranges::views::filter`, but using the *eager* `ranges::remove` instead which modifies the original containers (both need modifying).

The code below "works for me", but contains the UB as per OP:

```cpp
#include "range/v3/algorithm/remove.hpp"
#include "range/v3/view/zip.hpp"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class Integers {

  public:
    struct Iterator {
        using chunk             = std::array<int, 4>;
      
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag; // some requirements ommitted for brevity
        using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type        = chunk;
        using pointer           = value_type*;
        using reference         = value_type&;

        Iterator();
        Iterator(int* ptr) : current_row_(reinterpret_cast<chunk*>(ptr)) {}

        reference operator*() const { return *current_row_; }
        pointer   operator->() { return current_row_; }
        Iterator& operator++() {
            ++current_row_;
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator operator++(int) {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        friend std::ptrdiff_t operator-(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs) {
            return lhs.current_row_ - rhs.current_row_;
        }
        friend bool operator==(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) {
            return a.current_row_ == b.current_row_;
        }
        friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) {
            return a.current_row_ != b.current_row_;
        }

      private:
        chunk* current_row_;
    };

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&data_[0]); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(&data_[16]); }

    // fake the initialisation for brevity
    std::vector<int> data_{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
};

void print(const auto& zipped) {
    for (const auto& t: zipped) {
        for (auto i: t.first) std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << " | " << t.second << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

// no control over this api
void external_api(int* /* ptr */, std::size_t /* size */) {}

int main() {
    Integers chunked;

    std::vector<int> b{10, 20, 30, 40};

    auto zipped = ranges::views::zip(chunked, b);
    print(zipped);
    
    auto it = ranges::remove(zipped, 30, [](const auto& e) { return e.second; });

    auto relidx = it - zipped.begin();
    chunked.data_.erase(chunked.data_.begin() + relidx * 4, chunked.data_.end());
    b.erase(b.begin() + relidx, b.end());

    print(zipped);

    external_api(&chunked.data_[0], chunked.data_.size());
    
}
```

Output (as desired but based on UB):

```
1 2 3 4  | 10
5 6 7 8  | 20
9 10 11 12  | 30
13 14 15 16  | 40

1 2 3 4  | 10
5 6 7 8  | 20
13 14 15 16  | 40
```

## Current best alternative

My best current alternative is to hand code both "zip" and "remove" using messy raw loops that deal with the "chunk 4" logic. Below is one version of this, which is basically a modified version of the `std::remove` implementation:

```cpp
// no control over this api
void external_api(int* /* ptr */, std::size_t /* size */) {}

template <class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate, class ChunkedForwardIt>
ForwardIt remove_if_par(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p,
    ChunkedForwardIt chunked_first, std::ptrdiff_t chunk_size) {
    auto first_orig = first;
    first           = std::find_if(first, last, p);
    // advance chunked_first in lockstep. TODO this is linear compelxity unless random_access_iter
    std::advance(chunked_first, std::distance(first_orig, first) * chunk_size);
    if (first != last) {
        ForwardIt        i       = first;
        ChunkedForwardIt chunk_i = chunked_first;
        while (++i != last) {
            std::advance(chunk_i, chunk_size);
            if (!p(*i)) {
                *first++ = std::move(*i);
                // move chunk
                auto loop_chunk_i = chunk_i;
                for (std::ptrdiff_t ci = 0; ci != chunk_size; ++ci)
                    *chunked_first++ = std::move(*loop_chunk_i++);
            }
        }
    }
    return first;
}

void print(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& chunked, std::size_t chunk_size) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " | ";
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != chunk_size; ++j)
            std::cout << chunked[i * chunk_size + j] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
    std::vector<int> chunked{1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28};

    static constexpr std::ptrdiff_t chunk_size = 4;

    print(a, chunked, chunk_size);
    
    auto it = remove_if_par(
        a.begin(), a.end(), [](auto e) { return e % 20 == 0; }, chunked.begin(), chunk_size);

    print(a, chunked, chunk_size);
    
    a.erase(it, a.end());
    chunked.erase(chunked.begin() + (it - a.begin()) * chunk_size, chunked.end());

    print(a, chunked, chunk_size);
    
    external_api(&chunked[0], chunked.size());
}
```

Output  (as desired and without UB)

```
10 | 1 2 3 4 
20 | 5 6 7 8 
30 | 9 10 11 12 
40 | 13 14 15 16 
50 | 17 18 19 20 
60 | 21 22 23 24 
70 | 25 26 27 28 

10 | 1 2 3 4 
30 | 9 10 11 12 
50 | 17 18 19 20 
70 | 25 26 27 28 
50 | 17 18 19 20 
60 | 21 22 23 24 
70 | 25 26 27 28 

10 | 1 2 3 4 
30 | 9 10 11 12 
50 | 17 18 19 20 
70 | 25 26 27 28
```

I haven't checked, but I suspect that the assembly code generated for this "raw iterator loop" version is at least as good as any `range` based alternative; probably better.

Comment: This looks like you want [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried with `std::span` first, but how can it do the assignment of 4 ints via a single reference? I don't control the code in `copy()`, so I cannot use `std::copy` or a loop in there for example).

Comment: Why do you even need `copy`?  It al does it wrap `array_dest = array_source`.

Comment: The `copy` function looks like a hack job.  Can't you just skip using it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo
see above. `copy()` is not my code.  it's actually part of a an STL algorithm. All stripped for clarity.

Comment: @NathanOliver see above. copy() is not my code. it's actually part of a an STL algorithm. All stripped for clarity.

Comment: I've read that, it still doesn't explain why you need to use it.  Why can't you use a function that will actually work and not invoke UB?

Comment: Yes, I noiced that  `copy` is not your code, but why use it? Which STL algorithm is it? Why does it take `std::array<int, 4>&`? That's not how STL algorithms do. The stripping away for clarity is just confusing :-)

Comment: "an STL algorithm" would not use that specific function signature. Implicit copies in the standard library are achieved with the assignment operator. Explicit copies of containers typically use iterators. As always, the devil is in the details. Show a concrete example instead of a stripped-back simplified version.

Comment: the `std::array<int, N>&` is the return value of the `operator*()` of a custom iterator over the raw `int[]` , and that is what gets called by the STL algorithms as they perform they function and move elements around. I am using `std::ranges::remove`.

Comment: Maybe you can write a wrapper around a span where the assignment operator copies the data, rather than reassigning the spans?

Comment: *the std::array<int, N>& is the return value of the operator*() of a custom iterator over the raw int[]* This is UB.  You can't alias a C array as a `std::array`.

Comment: If you have an iterator over the `int[]` that dereferences to a `std::array<int, N>&` I think your UB starts there

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought maybe https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4.3 would apply?

Comment: @OliverSchönrock It would if the array you have was the member of the `std::array`, but it isn't.  The text you linked to requires that the two different types be part of the same object.

Comment: @Kevin Most useful idea here.. would appreciate a more complete answer.

Comment: Btw, if you can't change `copy`, can't you change your array to `std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 4> vals;`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Its a good thought, but no. My best alternative is to write several algorithms by hand with raw loops rather than use the STL ones and deal with the *4 chunks manually in the middle of that.

Comment: You should maybe add the high-level problem that you are trying to solve to your question.

Comment: @Kevin I tried your idea. But overriding assignment makes the iterator misbehave in so many ways.... Same old lesson, the special member functions should do what they normally do..

Comment: @OliverSchönrock I'm not sure what you mean. You should be overloading the assignment operator for the object the iterator returns, not the iterator itself. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're actually trying to do, this type of assignment is "normal". It's sort of like slice assignment in some other languages. Maybe you should edit your question to say what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep yes, it's definitely related to that

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's what I tried. But I found that even simple iteration with a ranged for loop then invokes this assignment operator and breaks the iteration. 
I am going to post a wider question.

Comment: @Kevin Wider context above

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wider context above

Comment: @NathanOliver wider context above

Comment: @Chronial wider context avoe

Comment: @Ranoiaetep wider context above

Comment: A workaround is to use `filter`: https://godbolt.org/z/Mxd19od7n

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yeah, that's good, and one of the things the guys from the ranges lib suggested. But this doesn't alter the original container does it? The filter is lazy, and that's fine if you are pulling it through while printing as you are. But I need to pass it to `external_api()`. Which would then require making a copy of the entire container? 

( the data is reasonably big and performance sensitive)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I have updated the Level 2 section to make it clear that I am looking for "modify in place".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed, `chunked_view` is not mutable. What you can do instead is to use `adjacent<N> | stride(n)` to create a mutable chunked view(assuming `N` is known at compile time):

```cpp
std::vector data {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
std::vector b{10, 20, 30, 40};
constexpr std::size_t chunk_size = 4;

auto chunked_view = data 
    | std::views::adjacent<chunk_size>
    | std::views::stride(chunk_size);
auto zipped_view = std::views::zip(chunked_view, b);

auto removed_range = std::ranges::remove(zipped_view, 30, [](auto pair){ return std::get<1>(pair); });

data.resize(data.size() - removed_range.size() * chunk_size);
b.resize(b.size() - removed_range.size());
```

Now `data` will be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,13,14,15,16`.

---

One thing to note is that `adjacent` creates a tuple of references of all the elements, so you can't iterate through a tuple. However, you can create a `span` or `views::counted` by using the address of the first element and `chunk_size`, since the underlying data were contiguous:

```cpp
for (auto& [tuple, key] : zipped_view) {
    for (auto i : std::span(&std::get<0>(tuple), chunk_size)) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << " | " << key << '\n';
}
```

---

You can also remove all the temporary views if desired, since all you needed from the remove function is how many elements were removed:

```cpp
std::vector data {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
std::vector b{10, 20, 30, 40};
constexpr std::size_t chunk_size = 4;

auto removal_size = 
    std::ranges::remove(
        std::views::zip(
            data | std::views::adjacent<chunk_size> | std::views::stride(chunk_size)
        , b) 
        , 30, [](auto pair){ return std::get<1>(pair); }
    ).size();

data.resize(data.size() - removal_size * chunk_size);
b.resize(b.size() - removal_size);
```

Comment: Very good!

 The ranges guys mentioned this in that github issue, but I couldn't make t work, because it's c++23. 

looks like gcc-trunk/libstdc++ can do it. https://godbolt.org/z/84MbKdx7a

they mentioned `adjacent_chunk` is that the equivalent in ranges-v3? For use today? 

Couldn't make that work

Comment: In this case I don't care about the "iterability" of the resulting `tuple` based view. I care about the state the underlying data, and that seems just fine. 

https://godbolt.org/z/7h6rf1djr

Just need a way to make it work with a released version of gcc. (ie via ranges-v3?) 

As expected the codegen looks significantly worse than the "raw iterator loop" solution I have above. But that's not a priority until it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock I don't know too much about range-v3, and I couldn't quite find `adjacent_chunk` in their documentation. However, you can simulate `adjacent<N>` with `zip(range, range | drop(1), range | drop(2), ... range | drop(N - 1))`, and even write a helper function with `index_sequence`. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/4KT7s7ojx

Comment: Creative solution! The code gen looks horrendous, but it certainly works nicely. 

I have accepted your answer because it comes closest to solving the problem, eventhough it is "futuretech". 

In practice I will stick with my raw iterator loop code until std::views::adacent is released with gcc > V13. But your solution is certainly preferable long term.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use a std::array<int, N> to alias parts of a int[] without invoking UB?

No.

> Is this UB?

Yes.

> Is there another way?

Depends on what parts of your scenario you can change.

> The `copy` function below is not under my control

Simplest solution would be to not use the `copy` function that's not useful for your use case.

> the `std::array<int, N>&` is the return value of the `operator*()` of a custom iterator over the raw `int[]`

Seems that there's probably no good way to implement such `operator*()`.

This seems like a good opportunity to define a custom range adaptor with custom assignment operators that you could return from the custom iterator.

Comment: `copy()` is part of an STL alhorithm.. std::remove. 

I thought that under some circumstances we can alias to the first member of a struct?

Comment: @OliverSchönrock `I thought that under some circumstances we can alias to the first member of a struct?` This is not such circumstance. `copy() is part of an STL alhorithm.. std::remove.` OK. Is that a problem?

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4.3

Comment: "is the first non-static data member of that object" -> "is", not "has the same type as".

Comment: @eerorika wider context now in question above... The custom range adapter sounds interesting..